# Django Can't See Where I Typed in User ID

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

So I'm creating a web app in Django, and I encountered this error:

[image]

my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:user_id>/', views.profile, name="profile"),
    #path('signup/', views.signup, name="signup"),
    path("signup/", views.signup, name="signup")
]
```

my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import forms
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.http import HttpResponse, Http404
from django.template import loader
from .models import User
from .forms import SignUpForm
from datetime import datetime

def index(request):
    cool_people_list = User.objects.order_by("-username")[:5]
    _template = loader.get_template("front_page.html")
    context = {
        "cool_people_list" : cool_people_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(_template.render(context, request))

def profile(request, user_id):
    try:
        user = get_object_or_404(User, pk=user_id)
        _template = loader.get_template("profile.html")
        context = {
            "user" : user
        }
        return HttpResponse(_template.render(context, request))
    except:
        raise Http404("The user you are looking for doesn't exist.")

def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            rn = str(datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%D"))
            rn2 = str(datetime.today)
            """usr_list = User.objects.order_by('-join_date')
            latest_usr = usr_list.first()"""
            new_user = User(3, str(form.cleaned_data.get("username")), str(form.cleaned_data.get("password")), rn, rn2)
            new_user.save()

    return render(request, "signup.html")
```

my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinLengthValidator
import datetime

class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=25, validators=[MinLengthValidator(3)])
    password = models.CharField(max_length=25, validators=[MinLengthValidator(7)])
    join_date = models.DateField()
    last_online = models.DateTimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

I kept trying different methods, like manually adding the user ID (temporary fix), but Django can't see where I type in the ID! It doesn't register it when I typed it in what I believe is the correct format for my 'User' model.

Comment: try this `new_user = User(user_id = 3,user_name= str(form.cleaned_data.get("username")), password=str(form.cleaned_data.get("password")),join_date= rn, last_online=rn2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save an object in `User` Model like this...

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        rn = datetime.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%D")
        rn2 = datetime.today
        new_user = User(username= form.cleaned_data["username"], password=form.cleaned_data["password"], rn=rn, rn2=rn2)
        new_user.save()
    else:
        form.errors
    return render(request, "signup.html")
```